# How do I apply all of my downloaded .tga textures to my model?

Tags: modeling, texturing, image, edit-mode, uv-image-editor

I've encountered an issue with my model's texture's within blender.

[image: How my model looks with with the UV Edit Mode.]

I was able to apply one of the TGA files by heading over to UV/Image Editor and selecting a file called Reptile_B1_Diff.tga

The file itself displays the entire model's textures. However, there are still other textures files that need to be included such as the eye ball and some kind of blue/purple body to my model as well.

But whenever I open those files containing the necessary texture, the entire model changes to the selected texture and doesn't stay with the texture that it had before.

Comment: UV image editor is used to **view** images unwrap models, you are not *applying* any textures to your model, only viewing them. To apply them you have to create materials that use said textures, search for tutorials about texturing in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with this scenario; it is common to have several texture maps assigned to a single model, especially in video games. You will need to know what geometry belongs to which texture, select that geometry, and *then* import and/or select the texture file in the UV Image Editor.

For example, the eye ball texture probably only belongs on the geometry that makes the eyes. So in edit mode, select only the eye geometry, and then in the UV editor you can select the appropriate texture. You can use things like the 'L' shortcut (select linked) to select connected geometry easily.